# Why does Veins crash when commandSetSpeedMode() is used?

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to simulate a scenario in Veins where I want to disable the
right of way checks at the road junctions. I looked up at the [Sumo wiki](http://www.sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Change_Vehicle_State) and
found that the bitset is **23** for the purpose. Another lookup in the
`TraCIMobility.h` header bundled with Veins helped me to know that this can
be done using the function `commandSetSpeedMode()` for a **TraCIDemo11p** node
which models the vehicles in the Veins demo simulation. I am trying to
build up my model using this demo bundled with Veins.

But as I am trying to do so, SUMO crashes. I am trying to initialize the
nodes in the `initialize()` function of `TraCIDemo11p` through the following
code:

```
void TraCIDemo11p::initialize(int stage) {
    BaseWaveApplLayer::initialize(stage);
    if (stage == 0) {
        traci = TraCIMobilityAccess().get(getParentModule());
        annotations = AnnotationManagerAccess().getIfExists();
        ASSERT(annotations);

        traci->commandSetSpeedMode(23);  // This is the point of modification

        sentMessage = false;
        lastDroveAt = simTime();
        findHost()->subscribe(parkingStateChangedSignal, this);
        isParking = false;
        sendWhileParking = par("sendWhileParking").boolValue();
    }
}
```

I tried to set the modes with other standard values such as 0 or 31, but
every time I get SUMO crashed.
I am unable to figure out where else I should place this command. I tried
to set the mode in some other initialization stage by adding an **else** clause
to it but it crashes still. What's more, eve nthe the debugger on, no error
is being shown, either in the OMNeT++ window or the `sumolaunchd.py` output
in OMNeT++ cmd.
Please help to understand my error. Thanks.

---

**EDIT:** adding Error message info

To make things clear, I am not receiving any error message but the exit code. I searched for the code but got no help. The usual 'this app is not responding' window pops up and the sim ends, so I suspect SUMO to crash.

The OMNeT++ environment shows the following message:

```
Simulation terminated with exit code: -1073741819
Working directory: C:/Users/stes-2/veins-3.0/examples/Cross Roads
Command line: c:/Users/stes-2/omnetpp-4.4/bin/opp_run.exe -r 0 -n ../veins;../../src --tkenv-image-path=../../images -l ../../src/veins omnetpp.ini

Environment variables:
OMNETPP_ROOT=c:/Users/stes-2/omnetpp-4.4
PATH=;C:/Users/stes-2/veins-3.0/src;c:\Users\stes-2\omnetpp-4.4\bin;c:\Users\stes-2\omnetpp-4.4\msys\bin;c:\Users\stes-2\omnetpp-4.4\mingw\bin;c:/Users/stes-2/omnetpp-4.4/ide/jre/bin/client;c:/Users/stes-2/omnetpp-4.4/ide/jre/bin;c:/Users/stes-2/omnetpp-4.4/ide/jre/lib/i386;.;C:\Users\stes-2\omnetpp-4.4\msys\local\bin;c:\Users\stes-2\omnetpp-4.4\mingw\bin;C:\Users\stes-2\omnetpp-4.4\msys\bin;c:\Users\stes-2\omnetpp-4.4\bin;c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\Windows\system32;c:\Windows;c:\Windows\System32\Wbem;c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\Python27;c:\Users\stes-2\sumo-0.21.0;c:\Users\stes-2\omnetpp-4.4;
OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=c:\Users\stes-2\omnetpp-4.4\images
```

Since I am running SUMO through the sumoLaunchd.py script, the error message that turns up at the MingW cmd of OMNeT++ is:

```
Starting SUMO (c:/Users/stes-2/sumo-0.21.0/bin/sumo-gui.exe -c cross.sumo.cfg) o
n port 64161, seed 0
Connecting to SUMO (c:/Users/stes-2/sumo-0.21.0/bin/sumo-gui.exe -c cross.sumo.c
fg) on port 64161 (try 1)
Releasing lock on port
Starting proxy mode
Done with proxy mode
Done with proxy mode, killing SUMO
SIGTERM
Done running SUMO
Cleaning up
Result: "<?xml version="1.0"?>
<status>
        <exit-code>15</exit-code>
        <start>1433944271</start>
        <end>1433944276</end>
        <status>Exited with error code 15</status>
        <stdout><![CDATA[Loading configuration... done.
]]></stdout>
        <stderr><![CDATA[]]></stderr>
</status>
"
Closing connection from 127.0.0.1 on port 64160
```

Comment: can you include the error message to the question?

Comment: try this and report back: 
`mobility = TraCIMobilityAccess().get(getParentModule());`
`traci = mobility->getCommandInterface();`
`traciVehicle = mobility->getVehicleCommandInterface();`
`traciVehicle->setSpeedMode(21);`

Comment: I have already done it. The error still shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing some lines.

You have assigned the **TraCIMobility** to `traci`, and then you don't even consider the general **commandInterface** and the **vehicleCommandInterface**

```
TraCIMobility* mobility = TraCIMobilityAccess().get(getParentModule());
TraCICommandInterface* traci = mobility->getCommandInterface(); /* missing command interface */
TraCICommandInterface::Vehicle* traciVehicle = mobility->getVehicleCommandInterface(); /* missing vehicle command interface */
traciVehicle->setSpeedMode(someNumber);
```

I even tried to compile your code but it complains that there is no method available for `TraCIMobility` called `commandSetSpeedMode()`. But that could be due to difference in Veins versions.

---

**[Multi-stage initialization](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec149)**

A module/variable you are trying to access might not be ready, i.e. still has not been created, by the time you are trying to use it. In that case the *multi-stage initialization* feature of OMNeT++ can be used.

This means a "task" may be delayed to a later stage of the initialization of the current module:

```
void SomeModule::initialize(int stage)
{
    ApplicationBase::initialize(stage);  /* ignore if causes error */

    if(stage == 0)
    {
        /* do this */

    else if (stage == 3)
    {
        /* do this later */
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I am using Veins 3.0 and in the header file `TraCIMobility.h`, `commandSetSpeedMode()` is a function.
And yes, I did try the code which you've written above by writing:

`traci = TraCIMobilityAccess().get(getParentModule());
traci->getCommandInterface()->setSpeedMode(23);`

But even this didn't work. I suspect that maybe I am putting my code in the wrong place. I tried setting this at a different initialization stage as well but the error still occurs. Moreover, the error occurs at any value that I give to the function.

Comment: Also, in my version of Veins, `getVehicleCommandInterface()` is not a defined function. `setSpeedMode()` is directly available with `TraCICommandInterface`

Comment: obviously we have different versions of Veins. I checked and confirmed that `commandSetSpeedMode()` is provided as you say in Veins 3.0. Also, I tried the code in the same place as yours and it worked for me in my version of Veins. Which version of SUMO you have? Consider updating Veins and SUMO to a compatible version with each other?

Comment: I am using SUMO 0.21.0. I installed all the components as per the tutorials page on Veins website so I don't think that's a problem.
Currently, I am working around the problem by setting this variable on a timer I have set for 1 s after the vehicle enters the simulation. I tried to do this in the initialization stages but no luck, so going for this one as of now.

Comment: instead of using a timer, you can use the **multi-stage initialization** feature of OMNeT++. This allows you to set up a variable (still) in the initialization phase, but towards the end, because this variable might rely on the creation of other modules which are not present at the exact time when you are looking for it: https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec149

Comment: @AayDee In case of need I added multi-stage initialization to the current answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. I experimented with some more initialization stages and found that the Speed Mode of a car is actually set after Stage 2 of a ´Car´node. So I changed the speed mode at stage 3 and now it's working fine without the timer.